Spark job failure when converting datatype of column from string to date
Getting below error while writing into destination:

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 18 in stage 15526.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 18.3 in stage 15526.0 (TID 3281950) (10.179.0.125 executor 1190): org.apache.spark.SparkDateTimeException: [CAST_INVALID_INPUT] The value '04/12/2024 01:37:07.000 AM' of the type "STRING" cannot be cast to "TIMESTAMP" because it is malformed. Correct the value as per the syntax, or change its target type.

Tried:

df_new= (df.withColumn("Date",to_date( to_timestamp("LastUpdateDate","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a"))))
dfnew = df..withColumn("Date", expr("try_cast(LastUpdateDateNew AS DATE)"))

#Convert string to timestamp
   df_new = df.withColumn("LastUpdateTimestamp", unix_timestamp("LastUpdateDate", "MM/dd/yyyy            hh:mm:ss:SSS a").cast("timestamp"))

   #Convert timestamp to date in mm/dd/YYYY format
   #df_new_bill = df_new.withColumn("date", to_date((col("LastUpdateTimestamp")), "MM/dd/yyyy"))




Hello, which Spark version are you using? I tried your first approach and this cast works on Spark 3.3.2

You can try this :
df_new = (df.withColumn("LastUpdateTimestamp",
                        unix_timestamp(col("LastUpdateDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a")
                        .cast("timestamp"))
          )

This should convert the input column LastUpdateDate to the required output LastUpdateTimestamp
